# One class classification alternative algorithms

Tags: algorithm, classification, svm, naivebayes

Are there any other algorithms except from SVM and PositiveNaiveBayesClassifier that i can use to do one class classification? The Positive Naive Bayes is only for text classification and i want to use except from SVM and another two.Any suggestions?

Comment: "positive naive bayes" is just a silly name to GMM with k=1 and diagonal covariance matrix, and it **is not** limited to NLP. It is as broad as any other classifier. In terms of the question itself, google "one-class classifier" you will find at least a hundread.

Comment: Yes but i don't want to use those who are only suitable for text classification.

Comment: I think your question belongs to statsexchange. To answer it: look at the material of outlier and anomaly detection. Parzen windows, density/mixture models, Bayesian stuff... More general: you can use all generative models. I also found a paper that uses Random Forest for one class classification (haven't tried that so far): https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00862706/document.

Comment: @Vivi again - GMM/NB is **not suitable ONLY for nlp**, it is suitable for anything

Answer (score 0):

There is one with CNN and gaussian noise [LINK](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-class-neural-network-in-keras-249ff56201c0)
The architecture consists of a feature extractor which is generally VGG16 followed by a Gaussian Noise network that adds another class by adding noise to input. Then at the end is the classifier which classifies it as either 1 or 0.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33813170)